# Specific sort a list of numbers separated by dots

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list:

```
L = ['1.1.1.', '1.1.10.', '1.1.11.', '1.1.12.', '1.1.13.', '1.1.2.', '1.1.3.', '1.1.4.']
```

I want to sort it in next order:

```
1.1.1.
1.1.2.
1.1.3.
1.1.4.
1.1.10.
1.1.11.
1.1.12.
1.1.13.
```

The following method does not produce a result:

```
L.sort(key=lambda s: int(re.search(r'.(\d+)',s).group(1)))
```

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Django, really.

Comment: What should happen when there is a `1.2.1` value in the list? What happens if there is `2.1.1`? Should the sort take all those in to account?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just get the last part, convert that to an int and return it as the key for comparison

```
print(sorted(L, key=lambda x: int(x.split(".")[2])))
```

If you want **all the parts to be considered**, you can do like this

```
print(sorted(L, key=lambda x: [int(i) for i in x.rstrip(".").split(".")]))
```

It removes `.` at the end of the strings, splits them based on `.` and then converts each and every part of it to an `int`. The returned list will be used for comparison.

You can read more about how various sequences will be compared by Python, [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types)

**Output**

```
['1.1.1.','1.1.2.','1.1.3.','1.1.4.','1.1.10.','1.1.11.','1.1.12.','1.1.13.']
```

Answer (score 6):

If you need to sort by *all* digits, produce a sequence of integers in the key function:

```
sorted(L, key=lambda v: [int(p) for p in v.split('.') if p.isdigit()])
```

This method is robust in the face of non-digit values between the dots.

Demo:

```
>>> L = ['1.1.1.', '1.1.10.', '1.1.11.', '1.1.12.', '1.1.13.', '1.1.2.', '1.1.3.', '1.1.4.']
>>> sorted(L, key=lambda v: [int(p) for p in v.split('.') if p.isdigit()])
['1.1.1.', '1.1.2.', '1.1.3.', '1.1.4.', '1.1.10.', '1.1.11.', '1.1.12.', '1.1.13.']
```

Your specific attempt only returns the second number in the list, which for your sample data is *always* `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://pypi.org/project/natsort/3.3.0/ or a similar library for comparing software versions.

Answer (score 0):

## If you want to sort Semantic Versioning tags with Python:

Do *not* implement this yourself! Instead, using the built-in [packaging](https://pypi.org/project/packaging/) library leads to a much cleaner and robuster solution:

```
from packaging.version import Version
versions = ['0.1.0-alpha', '0.1.0-alpha-2', '0.4.0', '0.3.1', '0.3.0', '0.2.0']
sorted_versions = sorted(versions, key=lambda elt: Version(elt))
```

See more details on Semantic Versioning [here](https://semver.org/)