# How to sort list of version tags in Python

Tags: python, versioning

I have a list with tags like this:

```
list = ['1.0.0','1.0.1','1.1.1','1.1.1.abc','2.20.11','2.0.10.abc2']
```

I want to sort it base on the first number, then second number, then third.

The output should be like this:

```
['1.0.0','1.0.1','1.1.1','1.1.1.abc','2.0.10.abc2','2.20.11']
```

I've tried to use sort like this:

```
list.sort(key=lambda x: (x[:x.find('.')], int(x[x.find('.')+1:x.index('.',x.find('.')+1)]) ) )
```

I can sort base on the first two numbers just fine, it's the third number that bothers me, because there might be a string part, and also the numbers might be two digits or more, I don't know how to exclude the last string part and only sort the numbers.

Any Ideas on this?

**Edit**

The problem with default sort is that, I wouldn't properly sort all the parts, for example it would put 4.35.7 before 4.9.2 for some reason, that why I need to explicitly sort base on each part. My problem is that there might be a string part followed by numbers.

Comment: Won't `sorted(['1.0.0','1.0.1','1.1.1','1.1.1.abc','2.20.11','2.0.10.abc2'])` do just this? I get the expected result..

Comment: Whatever custom type of sort you require, your example is not sufficient to demonstrate why the default `sort`/`sorted` does not work.

Comment: @Torxed I just made that list up, but it would, say 5.2.14 and 5.2.9, it would put 5.2.14 before 5.2.9

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It's not a duplicate of the above, it's a duplicate of [specific sort a list of numbers separated by dots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361604/specific-sort-a-list-of-numbers-separated-by-dots)

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/natsort/3.3.0/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sorted` with a `key`.

You indeed need to use `str.split` to split the string into tokens. This will allow you to rely on list ordering.

Although, you will need to cast strings of digits to `int` first to get the expected result, otherwise numbers will be sorted in alphabetical order instead of numercial order.

### Example

```
l = ['1.0.0','1.0.1','1.1.1','1.1.1.abc','2.20.11','2.0.10.abc2']
sorted_l = sorted(l, key=lambda x: [int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in x.split('.')])
```

### Output

```
['1.0.0', '1.0.1', '1.1.1', '1.1.1.abc', '2.0.10.abc2', '2.20.11']
```

Comment: I tried this, it would put  4.35.7 before 4.9.4 for some reason

Comment: @Anna I'm sorry, I simply forgot to split on dots, it should be `x.split('.')` instead of `x.split()`. This one works now

Comment: it's still doing that, this is what I put in: tags_sorted = sorted(tags,key = lambda x: [int(i) if i.isnumeric() else i for i in x.split('.')]), but it's putting 4.9.4 before 4.35.7

Comment: Well, 4.9.4 *should* be before 4.35.7

Comment: sorry, type it wrong, it's putting 4.35.7 before 4.9.4

Comment: What is the full input you are using? It works for me

Comment: Since 9 is less than 35, it is returning wrong results. this solution does not take care of decimal position.

Comment: Sorry, my bad again, I output the wrong thing, it works!!

Comment: @Anna Glad I could help!